# Where can I find data to track migration out of Puerto Rico?

Tags: data-request, migration, travel

I am looking to track the migration of Puerto Rican nationals out of Puerto Rico post the devastating hurricanes. What datasets would be most effective for this? Travel data, flight data, etc.